# CSS interrupt when use bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transition

I am making make a nav button which transforms from 3 lines to x

```js
    var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    [].forEach.call(anchor, function(anchor) {
      var open = false;
      anchor.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!open) {
          this.classList.add('close');
          open = true;
        } else {
          this.classList.remove('close');
          open = false;
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Source Sans pro", sans-serif;
}
#mbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
#mbtn span {
  display: block;
}
.lines-button {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* */
}
.lines {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 0.57143rem;
  background: #211f20;
  border-radius: 0.28571rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}
.lines:before,
.lines:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 0.57143rem;
  background: #211f20;
  border-radius: 0.28571rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0.28571rem center;
  transform-origin: 0.28571rem center;
}
.lines:before {
  top: 1rem;
}
.lines:after {
  top: -1rem;
}
.lines-button:hover .lines:before {
  top: 1.14286rem;
}
.lines-button:hover .lines:after {
  top: -1.14286rem;
}
.lines-button.close {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
  transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
}
.lines-button.x.close .lines {
  background: transparent;
}
.lines-button.x.close .lines:before,
.lines-button.x.close .lines:after {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 4rem;
}
.lines-button.x.close .lines:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
}
.lines-button.x.close .lines:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" role="button" aria-label="Toggle Navigation" id="mbtn" class="lines-button x">
  <span class="lines"></span>
</button>
```

it works perfectly when i remove bootstrap.min.css from html, but when i have my bootstrap css it makes an interference with actual navs css and is not working properly

Answer (score 5):

the issue is because `bootstrap` already has styles for `.close` class replace the `.close` class styles with any other name

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Ah6XA/33/

included `bootstrap.min.css` in this fiddle

replaced `.close` to `.change`

```
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');

[].forEach.call(anchor, function (anchor) {
    var open = false;
    anchor.onclick = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!open) {
            this.classList.add('change');
            open = true;
        } else {
            this.classList.remove('change');
            open = false;
        }
    }
});
```

css styles

```
.lines-button.change {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
}
.lines-button.x.change .lines {
    background: transparent;
}
.lines-button.x.change .lines:before, .lines-button.x.change .lines:after {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 4rem;
}
.lines-button.x.change .lines:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
}
.lines-button.x.change .lines:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
}
```